# symfony batch action security

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, admin-generator

my `security.yml`:

```
all:
  is_secure: true

new:
  credentials: [add_ticker_source]
edit:
  credentials: [edit_ticker_source]
delete: 
  credentials: [delete_ticker_source]
batchDelete: //I don't know whether it is correct. Should it be batch_delete?
  credentials: [delete_ticker_source]
batch_delete: 
  credentials: [delete_ticker_source]

index: 
  is_secure: false
```

in my `generator.yml`, I added

```
  list:
    batch_actions:
      _delete: {credentials: delete_ticker_source}
```

then I commented last two lines and opened list view in my browser. So in my list view in the browser, I can see delete in the drop-down of batch actions. Now, I uncommented them and didn't refresh the browser. I selected some elements from the list view, selected delete in the batch drop-down and hit `go`. These items get deleted instantly. Does that mean batch delete is not secure?? Or could anyone delete by sniffing around??

I even tried clearing cache after uncommenting but then also, the elements are deleted.

P.S. : and no, the user I'm logged in with, does not have `delete_ticker_source` credentials(as told by web debug bar).

Comment: What credentials does your account have?

Comment: With this settings in `generator.yml` and without this permission, `_delete` batch action must disappear from the select. Also `batchDelete: credentials: [delete_ticker_source]` should work fine. Thinking out loud... did you put `security.yml` in module config folder? ... and also did you override the template _list_batch_actions.php?

Comment: @macgyver : I think you misunderstood the question. I commented last two lines ie essentially made batch_actions: ~
So batch delete will be visible to me. Then I un commented them and cleared cache. Then I pressed go. It didn't check my permissions. Why?

Comment: And good thinking by the way. but sadly, I didn't override batch template and security.yml is right alongside generator.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your settings and yet I'm wonder of this unexpected behaviour. So I surfed inside the code and finally I found that to secure the `batchDelete` action we have to put the setting inside the `generator.yml` in this way, under *config > actions*:

```
config:
  actions:
    batchDelete:
      credentials: [user_permission]
```

Obiviously `user_permission` is `delete_ticker_source` for you.

Comment: hmmm.. You are right. Then what's the use of `security.yml` in admin generated modules? I mean, we could just write security settings in `generator.yml`. Secondly, It seems to be odd behavior. Should I open a ticket?

Comment: As you can try, securing `new`, `edit` and (no batch) `delete` actions through `security.yml` works and also through `generator.yml` under *config > actions*, so we can say this is a redundancy and maybe with the first choice we get a "cleaner" coding. But with this exception, or bug (?), we get a "dirtier" coding... maybe opening a ticket could clear this dilemma.